# Audio jack detection to turn on device without power loss

Tags: power-supply, switches, audio, connector

I'm trying to make simple headphones amp and I wonder - is there any way to use stereo jack connector with N-C switches like this: [image: PJ-324M]
to turn on the amp so the battery is mechanically disconnected?

I mean that, if my connectors had N-O switches, it would be easy, but with N-C I have no idea, whether it's even possible to make such "smart" power on, without any power loss (i.e. powering some transistors/logic gates that detect open circuit etc.) or maybe should I seek for female connector with N-O switches?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really for a stereo headphone, but you can do it for a mono jack by hooking the battery negative lead to the ring contact on a stereo socket... Classic guitar pedal trick.

About the best you can do is a mosfet with a 22M resistor to bias the gate and use one of the headphone switches to pull the gate down when nothing is inserted.

Regards, Dan.

Comment: Thanks, mono jack won't do unfortunately, but mosfet should do, nice one